# Snowflake Query returns Http status: Unprocessable Entity

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm able to successfully connect to the Snowflake database through my .NET app, but I'm unable to run a SQL command due to the following error from the Snowflake:

Message: `Http status: UnprocessableEntity`

ResponseContent:

```
"code" : "391920",   
"message" : "Unable to run the command. You must specify the warehouse to use by either setting the warehouse field in the body of the request or by setting the DEFAULT_NAMESPACE property for the current user.",
"sqlState" : "57P03",   
"statementHandle" : "01a8
```

Here is my code I'm using.

```
public async Task<QueryResult> QuerySnowflake(string statement, string database, string schema)
{
    var content = new
    {
        statement,
        database,
        schema
    };

    return await _httpClient.SnowflakePost<QueryResult>($"https://{_accountId}.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements", content, await GetHeaders(), _cancellationToken);
}
```

statement = `SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER`
database = `SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA`
schema = `TPCH_SF1`

I have already tried the following:

- `ALTER USER my_username SET DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1`
- `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "TPCH_SF1" TO ROLE sysadmin`
- `ALTER USER my_username SET DEFAULT_ROLE = sysadmin`

All of these did not change the error response.

I don't think it needs a code change as it works with other Snowflake accounts (I'm using a new trial account). I believe I have my something wrong with my account (e.g. missing role, missing warehouse, missing permission, etc).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user does not have a default warehouse and none is specified in the connection request or a use command in the session. You can try sending this command before running your select:

```
use warehouse MY_WAREHOUSE;
```

You can also specify it in the connection, or specify a default for the user:

```
ALTER USER MY_USER SET DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE = MY_WAREHOUSE;
```

Comment: The `SET DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE` solved my issue. Thank you!